# Run the same for loop's different iterations at the same time

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, iteration

There was another question like this but the answer wasn't clear

Trying to make a for loop faster by running each iteration at the same time

```
for i in something:
   print(i) # I would want this code to be executed all at the same time
```

Comment: The exact question is unclear as the provided example is linear. In fact, a question has not been asked.

Comment: You will need to use Multi threading or Multi processing to do what you want.

I suggest you search about those subjects and ask if you have any trouble implementing it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still requires a for loop, but Im assuming the code inside each loop is lengthy and takes time, so heres how you could start a thread for each loop then wait till all threads are finished before continuing

```
import threading

def myfunc(*args):
    #do something
    return

threads=[]

for n,i in enumerate(something):
     threads.append(threading.Thread(target = myfunc, args = (i,))) #args needs to be a tuple, even with only 1 element
     threads[n].start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```